# LQ decomposition

Tags: matrices

so I'm studying for Dirty Paper Coding on MU-MIMO, the system needs LQ decomposition in it. and I want to ask, where do we get the value of L (as in lower matrix triangular) from this case? can anyone help? thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Take an under-determined matrix $A$ and take the transpose, $A^{T}$. Now take the $QR$ decomposition. Now take the transpose of each $Q,R$

$ A = R^{T}Q^{T}$

Like below with some python code.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(10,20)

At  = np.transpose(A)

Q,R = np.linalg.qr(At)

Rt = np.transpose(R) 
Qt = np.transpose(Q)

error = np.linalg.norm(A - np.dot(Rt,Qt))
print(error)

2.023080674308577e-15
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a generalization of [*QR decomposition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#QL.2C_RQ_and_LQ_decompositions). You can read more about *LQ* decomposition [here.](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node41.html)

Comment: thank you, it's from gram-schmidt's methode and R matrix transpose, now I get it. thank you

Comment: @NadhiaIffahSaraswati You're welcome. The point is not that. Here $L$ is a lower triangle matrix, and $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix. How to produce the decomposition is another question. I think analogously, like in the *QR* decomposition, you can use also [Householder transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Using_Householder_reflections) or [Givens rotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition#Using_Givens_rotations).