# Differences between QR and LQ matrix decomposition

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I'm supposed to do a variety of matlab experiments for different factorizations and two of those are QR and LQ factorizations, which for matrix $A$ ${m \times n}$ yield $$A=Q[R_1\;R_2]$$
where $R_1$ is upper triangular of order m, $R_2$ is $m\times(n-m)$ and Q is orthogonal of order m, and
$$A=[L\;0]Q,$$
where $L$ is lower triangular of order m, Q is orthogonal of order n.
Supposedly LQ is calculated by applying QR on $A^T$ and transposing it back.

I found very few resources regarding LQ factorization, so my question is, why would we ever really want to use LQ instead of QR? I'm not sure about its purpose.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/918177/1198970) answer your question?

Comment: It helps, but I'm still not sure what benefit (maybe in terms of numerical stability or something of that sort) using LQ instead of QR would bring

Comment: To my best knowledge, it has no numerical advantage. They are essentially the same, [see](https://netlib.org/lapack/lug/node41.html).